# How to fix 'Design assumption violated' error in ViewPager2?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I'm using ViewPager2, Kotlin and AndroidX.
When the adapter is not at index 0 and I change the adapter list and set current item to index 0 the exception is thrown.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Design assumption violated.
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.updateCurrentItem(ViewPager2.java:538)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2$4.onAnimationsFinished(ViewPager2.java:518)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator.isRunning(RecyclerView.java:13244)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:515)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
```

In line 537 of ViewPager2 there is an if which causes the exception:

```
        // Extra checks verifying assumptions
        // TODO: remove after testing
        View snapView1 = mPagerSnapHelper.findSnapView(mLayoutManager);
        View snapView2 = mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(snapPosition);
        if (snapView1 != snapView2) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Design assumption violated.");
        }
```

This is how I'm updating the adapter list:

```
adapter.list = newList
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
viewpager.setCurrentItem(0, true)
```

It happens only when `smoothScroll` is set to `true`

What am I missing?

**Edit :**
I'm using `androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2` available in `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08`

Comment: I'm seeing that setting the adapter's list to a new list automatically moves the pager to the first item.. so there really is nothing to scroll by the time `setCurrentItem` is called.

Comment: @glucaio when the new list has more items than the previous list, the index is not set to 0.

Comment: You're right. I'm seeing that as well. File a bug maybe? Setting the current item definitely seems to be a work in progress still.

Comment: @Amir can you share the sample project of your code as git repo? so we can try to help you

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had this same problem with **ViewPager2** on configuration change. I'm using:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta03'
```

In my case, I had overridden the `getItemId()` method in my **FragmentStateAdapter** class. When I got rid of my `getItemId()` method, the "*IllegalStateException: Design assumption violated*" error was no more! :-)

Comment: For anyone who encounters this issue but cannot remove their custom implementation of `getItemId()`, you should also override `containsItem(long)`. This is indicated in the Javadocs

Comment: @PatrickGrayson's comment is the real answer for this problem

Answer (score 19):

I'm using `androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0`

For whoever still stuck at this, and need to implement `getItemId()` `containsItem()`. Please chek your `getItemId()` and `containsItem()` implementation. My problem is when I serve 10 item with **possibility several item have same value**, this error occurs.

Media have several data with same value.

```
private var mediaId = media.map { it.hashCode().toLong() }

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = mediaId[position]

override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean = mediaId.contains(itemId)
```

while you updating the data or even simply swiping, the viewpager is confuse because you implement `getItemId()` with non unique id. The solution is just **make sure your data is unique or have their own id**. *My media datas dont have id.

> If you open the implementation of `getItemId()` notes this part :
>
> - @return stable item id {@link RecyclerView.Adapter#hasStableIds()}
>
> you need to have unique id for each of item.

Comment: I did implent getItemId(), is it a must?, i am using material 1.3.0

Comment: if you have unique id in every data or you can ensure your data never duplicate,so you don't have to do this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but the bug seems to be fixed (at least for me) in the current version `androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta01`.

See more in [ViewPager2 1.0.0-beta01 Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0-beta01)

Comment: I'm using `androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2` available in `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08`

Comment: It is the same ViewPager2 library as `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08` depends on `androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-alpha06`. You have to wait, until Material Components library will be updated to use `androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta01`, or you can force to use current ViewPager2 library version with `implementation("androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta02")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for a straightforward use case

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter

class ViewPager2Adapter(
val dataList: List<Item> = listOf(),
fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity
) :
FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {

val pageIds= dataList.map { it.hashCode().toLong() }.toMutableList()

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return MyFragment.newInstance(dataList[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return dataList.size
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return pageIds[position]
}

override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean {
    return pageIds.contains(itemId)
}
}
```

Then I encountered a specific use case when I was replacing my object at the position with a new one then I got the exception.

**Solution:**
Now in case you are making data changes to the adapter i.e. with replacing an object in dataList with a new one, then make sure to replace id in **pageIds** of the old object with the new one.

```
(viewPager2.adapter as? ViewPager2Adapter)?.apply {
pageIds[oldIndex] = (NewItemObject).hashCode().toLong()
notifyItemChanged(oldIndex)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My issue was that I was customizing `containsItem()` to have some conditions under which I remove Fragments from the `ViewPager`, and then return `false`;

I encounter `Design assumption violated` after rotating the phone (and then swipe the `ViewPager2`).

I solved that by just returning the super class method: `return super.containsItem(itemId);`

```
@Override
public boolean containsItem(long itemId) {
    // Your code
    return super.containsItem(itemId);
}
```

UPDATE:

> The containsItem method does not have the "CallSuper" annotation and is therefore not required to be called

This is right, no need to call the super; and I didn't call it explicitly before returning a boolean; just returning it solving this issue

Comment: The containsItem method does not have the "CallSuper" annotation and is therefore not required to be called

Comment: @DennisVA FYI you don't have to call it.. but you *must* return a boolean, and whenever you don't want to explicitly return true/false you return the supper class method.. my issue raised whenever I returning an explicit value.. so I solved it by returning the super class method instead!

Comment: if you just called the super class then it would be the same as removing this block of code right?

Comment: @chitgoks I didn't get you.. you would call the super class and return what?

Comment: @zain i meant that if you only called return super.containsItem(itemId);
 then it is the same as removing that method. so there is no need to put that.

Comment: @chitgoks I had to override that method.. If you noticed I just omitted my code withe the comment *//Your code*... When i returned false the problem appears.. But by returning the super class the problem solved.

Comment: ok. ViewPager2 is a pain. I wasted time migrating it to this because i figured they would remove ViewPager anytime sooner than later. But the animation is so slow, it does not look good when used with tabs. The actionbar menuitem changes only when the animation is done. 

regarding the issue in this post, containsItem() didnt work out. getItemId() alone, worked ok.